# Does kubernetes support alternative repository when pull or applying a deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

To minimize network problems, I created a `local repository`, mirroring `Docker Hub`. When applying a deployment, my local registry goes down. Is it possible to automatically change repository source to Docker Hub instead of my local repository? Applying then, redundancy.

Like:

```
...
containers:
- name: webserver
  image-1: registry.mydomain/nginx:latest
  image-2: nginx:latest
  imagePullPolicy: Always
...
```

Comment: An alternative is to use something like nexus to proxy the container registry. That maintains a local cache of images so it will only go to Dockerhub if the image isn't already in the local cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kubernetes pod spec [doesn't include the functionality to specify multiple container images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#container-v1-core), but the underlying container runtime can often be configured to do that.

#### Docker

When a specific prefix domain is not provided for an image, The `docker.io` registry is the first place Docker looks for an unscoped image. This is why `docker pull mysql` works. Docker has a `registry-mirrors` setting to modify this behaviour.

In `daemon.json` add:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [ "something.local" ],
}
```

This will cause Docker to look for non scoped images on `something.local` first,  then `docker.io`.